# LookAhead not working in JFlex

Tags: regex, nlp, flex-lexer, jflex

I am trying to use JFlex to build a parser but encounter a very basic issue.
I want to have this token

```
[A-Za-z]+_N$ { System.out.println("Noun"); }
```

and have it recognize "car_N" as a "Noun" and NOT recognize "car_NN".
but it does not work, if I use

```
[A-Za-z]+_N { System.out.println("Noun"); }
```

"car_N" get recognize but "car_NN" returns "car_N" as well, this is not what I want.

I wonder anyone here knows how to help?

JFlex and Flex lookahead symbol '$' does not seem to be working

Answer (score 4):

I think you're misunderstanding the meaning of '$'.  As a lookahead, it matches only at the end of a line of text (hard-line break).  As such it works perfectly fine.  But it cannot differentiate between car_N and car_NN, except for instances of car_N that are at the very end of a line.  Maybe you really want a lookahead something like:

```
[A-Za-z]+_N/[^A-Za-z]
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that you dropped by stackoverflow, I working with William Cohen btw..